# (xenial-backports/main amd64) Packages server certificate verification failed

Tags: apt

I tried to install `gfortran` by writing `sudo apt-get install gfortran` but the terminal simply showed

```
Enable to locate the packages for gfortran
```

So I again tried by writing

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and it gives error.

Error is as shown below:

```
Err:65 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

Can anybody suggest what I should do?

Comment: `xenial-backports` why do you have that repository?

Comment: Well since I am using ubuntu for the first time. I dont know that much. May be because I was trying to install by reading it from here and there only, I did something unintentionally.  Could you please suggest something to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apt-cache policy gfortran` reveals that it is available in main Ubuntu repository. And since this error is about `backport` repository, you can safely ignore this. Proceed with

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran
```

To install the package.

Check this AU question to know about backport repository

> - [What are the differences between "precise" and "precise-updates" and "precise-backports"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496295/what-are-the-differences-are-between-precise-and-precise-updates-and-precis)

Comment: well i proceeded as such too but still there are still some errors.

Comment: Edit your question with the errors you found.

Comment: @KavitaRani these are not errors. You'll type `Y` and hit Enter

Comment: well I did that too

Comment: and will come back If I will not be able to do it in the right way.