# What is the difference between <suite> and <suite>-security repositories in apt?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, repository, official-repositories

I know about the difference between, for example, `focal-security`, `focal-updates` and `focal-backports`.
But `/etc/apt/sources.list` also has URLs for `focal` in addition to the others.

This is confusing. Is `focal` only what came packaged with the distro release? Or what was available at that point in time?
Or is it the initial version 1.0 of every package? Does it not get security updates?
Also, what's it called? The "default" repo / channel?

What would happen, for example, if I had only `focal` enabled, or only `focal-security` enabled?
What's the point in making a distinction between those two repos? Or is it just an alias for `focal-security`?

---

Related (but doesn't quite answer specifically about this difference):

- [What is bionic-updates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119799/what-is-bionic-updates)
- [What are the differences between "precise" and "precise-updates" and "precise-backports"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496295/what-are-the-differences-between-precise-and-precise-updates-and-precise-ba)
- [What is the difference between security, updates, proposed and backports in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401941/what-is-the-difference-between-security-updates-proposed-and-backports-in-etc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is addressed in [the Security Team FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ#How_are_the_.22-updates.22_and_.22-security.22_pockets_different.3F):

> #### How are components and pockets used in the builds, and how do they affect security updates?
>
> [...]
>
> Ubuntu also has several pockets that further divide the archive:
> `release`, `security`, `updates`, `proposed` and `backports`. [...]
> The release pocket is simply the name of the release, and the other
> pockets are denoted by `<release name>-<pocket>`. For example, the
> release pocket for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, the Xenial Xerus, is simply
> `xenial`, while the security pocket for Ubuntu
> 16.04 LTS is `xenial-security`. Packages in `release`, `security` and `updates` are supported by the Ubuntu Security team, while packages in
> `backports` are supported by the community and packages in `proposed`
> are the responsibility of the uploader. When packages are built, only
> certain pockets are available during the build:
>
> - **release**: during the development cycle, this is the only pocket
>   that is used. Once the development version is released, the release
>   pocket is frozen and does not change.
> - **security**: built with `release` and `security`.
>   [UpdateProcedures](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/UpdateProcedures)
>   gives the process
>   used for creating security updates.
> - **proposed**: built with `release`, `security`, `updates` and `proposed`
> - **updates**: as a matter of Ubuntu policy, packages in `updates` are not directly built, but rather copied from `proposed` after they
>   have been tested. See
>   [StableReleaseUpdates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates)
>   for details. If a special circumstance warrants building a package in
>   `updates` without going through `proposed` first, it would be built
>   with `release`, `security` and `updates` (also, the default
>   configuration for unofficial PPAs is to build with this
>   configuration).
> - **backports**: built with `release`, `security`, `updates` and `backports`. See
>   [UbuntuBackports](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuBackports) for
>   details.
>
> #### What repositories and pockets should I use to make sure my systems are up to date?
>
> - By default, Ubuntu systems have both the `security` and `updates` pockets enabled. Systems configured to use only the `security` pocket
>   are also supported.
> - While packages are copied from `security` to `updates` frequently, it is recommended that systems always have the `security` pocket
>   enabled, and use `security.ubuntu.com` for this pocket. For all other
>   pockets feel free to use `archive.ubuntu.com` or an [archive
>   mirror](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors){.https}. This
>   combination will ensure you are able to download important updates
>   immediately while taking advantage of the mirror network or
>   `archive.ubuntu.com` for all other downloads. Ubuntu systems are
>   configured in this manner by default.

---

So:

> Is `focal` only what came packaged with the distro release?

Yes.

> Does it not get security updates?

No.

> Also, what's it called?

The "release" pocket.

> What would happen, for example, if I had only `focal` enabled, or only `focal-security` enabled?

With only `focal` enabled, you'd be effectively limited to being able to install packages included in initial 20.04 release. With only `focal-security` enabled, you'd have a broken system, since you would quickly run into dependency problems (since not all dependencies would have had security updates, so some would still be only in `focal`).

Comment: Thanks! That explains a lot! So, would it be right to assume universe and multiverse pkgs are never in "release" pocket? I suppose since they are not "main" (officially supported) they wouldn't be bundled with a Ubuntu installation, right? Also, does "release" pocket apply to point releases too, like 20.04.1?

Comment: No, components are orthogonal to pockets. All packages in all components at the time of release are frozen in the release pocket.

Comment: So, every time a package is built, that build is associated with both a component and pocket? You can think of it as each component can be subdivided into each pockets, or that each pocket can be subdivided into each component. Any combination of components and pockets will have packages. Any builds included in an Ubuntu distribution when the distribution was made will go into the release pocket. This doesn't mean they came installed with the distribution though, it just means that you can apt install them without having to first bring in any external repositories / PPAs. Is this all correct?

Comment: @KevinWheeler I'm not sure about the build time association. IIRC a particular when Ubuntu does an update of a package in a stable release, it starts in`-proposed` and then moves to `-updates` or `-security` without (necessarily) changing versions in between, so a particular build can be associated with different pockets at different times. The rest seems correct.