# Unable to install systemd-container ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, software-installation, dependencies, systemd

I tried to install systemd-container on brand new ubuntu 20.04 but I have following message:

```
sudo apt-get install systemd-container
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 systemd-container : Depends: systemd (= 245.4-4ubuntu3)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But it's not obvious how to fix it because when I try, getting this

```
sudo apt install systemd=245.4-4ubuntu3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 policykit-1 : Depends: libpam-systemd but it is not going to be installed
 systemd : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 245.4-4ubuntu3) but 245.4-4ubuntu3.2 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

And so one till libpam-systemd

```
sudo apt install libpam-systemd=245.4-4ubuntu3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpam-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 245.4-4ubuntu3)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And at this point, we got a circle.

EDIT: found that I can

```
$ sudo apt download systemd-container 
$ sudo dpkg --force-all -i systemd-container_245.4-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

And it's working but I got dependency errors all the time.

Is there any better workaround?

EDIT 2:

apt-cache output

```
apt-cache policy systemd systemd-container
systemd:
  Installed: 245.4-4ubuntu3.2
  Candidate: 245.4-4ubuntu3.2
  Version table:
 *** 245.4-4ubuntu3.2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     245.4-4ubuntu3 500
        500 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
systemd-container:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 245.4-4ubuntu3
  Version table:
     245.4-4ubuntu3 500
        500 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

EDIT 3:

Quick way to reproduce error on ubuntu 20.04:

```
adam@adam:~/$ systemd-nspawn

Command 'systemd-nspawn' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install systemd-container

adam@adam:~/$ sudo apt install systemd-container
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 systemd-container : Depends: systemd (= 245.4-4ubuntu3)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Best

Comment: Sounds like your apt system has dependancy issues can occur for a number of reasons..

Start with a apt update

Comment: Followed by a 

 apt-get update --fix-missing

Comment: All packages are updated, problem occurs because ubuntu 20 comes with  newer wersion of systemd that is required. See [package-link](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/admin/systemd-container)

Comment: It's not because everytime I install something or upgrade I got following message                                            `You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these` (unmet dependecies)

Comment: @N0rbert Thank you for posting this, but the problem is different. I got the correct repositories and apt tries to download the correct package version but this correct version is not matching the system installed packages - you can see on the package-link I've sent before that package version is the newest from the ubuntu repo. Even though it's the newest installed systemd is newer than needed and can't be downgraded.

Comment: Please show the output of `apt-cache policy systemd systemd-container` . The correct version of both is [*245.4-4ubuntu3.5*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/systemd-container).

Comment: @ElderGeek It's not the case of correcting problems, I posted edit 3 for understand core of problem.

Comment: @AdamKrawczyk My apologies if I misinterpreted your post. Pleas edit in the output of `dpkg -l | grep ^..r`

Comment: No problem @ElderGeek I'm thankful for your activity. Unfortunately no package is matching regex ```dpkg -l | grep ^..r```.

Comment: @AdamKrawczyk please [edit] and add the output of `grep /etc/apt/sources.list focal` and the output of `ls -a  /etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing your edits, I did some digging and below is the relevant part of what I found in the Packages.gz file at http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/ by tracing your output from your apt-cache output. As mentioned by [N0rbert](https://askubuntu.com/users/66509/n0rbert) in the comments, It appears that the repository you are using has out of date versions of the packages that you require as seen below. You can find the up to date versions in the focal-updates repository [here.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/allpackages) I highly recommend you replace the pl.archive.ubuntu.com repository that you are using with the default repository from the Main server or the US archive both of which appear to be up to date. See [this answer.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) There's a great related Q&A regarding the different sources [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279002/what-is-the-difference-between-suite-and-suite-security-repositories-in-apt)

```
Package: systemd
Architecture: amd64
Version: 245.4-4ubuntu3
Multi-Arch: foreign
Priority: important
Section: admin
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian systemd Maintainers <pkg-systemd-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 15084
Pre-Depends: libblkid1 (>= 2.24), libc6 (>= 2.30), libgcrypt20 (>= 1.8.0), liblz4-1 (>= 0.0~r122), liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614), libselinux1 (>= 2.1.9)
Depends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.23), libapparmor1 (>= 2.9.0-3+exp2), libaudit1 (>= 1:2.2.1), libcap2 (>= 1:2.24-9~), libcrypt1 (>= 1:4.4.0), libcryptsetup12 (>= 2:2.0.1), libgnutls30 (>= 3.6.12), libgpg-error0 (>= 1.14), libidn2-0 (>= 2.0.0), libip4tc2 (>= 1.8.3), libkmod2 (>= 5~), liblz4-1 (>= 0.0~r130), libmount1 (>= 2.30), libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1), libpcre2-8-0 (>= 10.22), libseccomp2 (>= 2.4.1), libsystemd0 (= 245.4-4ubuntu3), systemd-timesyncd | time-daemon, util-linux (>= 2.27.1), mount (>= 2.26), adduser
Recommends: dbus, networkd-dispatcher
Suggests: systemd-container, policykit-1
Conflicts: consolekit, libpam-ck-connector, systemd-shim, upstart
Breaks: python-dbusmock (<< 0.18), python3-dbusmock (<< 0.18), systemd-shim (<< 10-4~)
Filename: pool/main/s/systemd/systemd_245.4-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb
Size: 3795776
MD5sum: 2529c1980daa1f26dab931b1b739f196
SHA1: 29a79ae4edee4964ac34ddba0fd0a47c2c4a49d0
SHA256: f081921d83e6378aee0576a1e3f1339a35c9302c46fc501b087cd762145597d8
Homepage: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd
Description: system and service manager
Task: minimal, ubuntu-core
Description-md5: 19399579cbc0c47a303288bf15eadcd4

Package: systemd-container
Architecture: amd64
Version: 245.4-4ubuntu3
Multi-Arch: foreign
Priority: optional
Section: admin
Source: systemd
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian systemd Maintainers <pkg-systemd-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 1191
Depends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.23), libbz2-1.0, libc6 (>= 2.28), libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.3), libgcrypt20 (>= 1.8.0), liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614), libseccomp2 (>= 2.3.1), libselinux1 (>= 2.1.9), systemd (= 245.4-4ubuntu3), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4), dbus
Recommends: libnss-mymachines
Filename: pool/main/s/systemd/systemd-container_245.4-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb
Size: 317240
MD5sum: f67b429ff0cf3fb51bfdd18c2785b445
SHA1: 0eb815d5050e8c25c635f33870d72b5ae9357dbb
SHA256: 54ce1e0c2d1ea5d43db6f5a02b9f5b3731d9e1c2c653ee2c835aae89b899a664
Homepage: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd
Description: systemd container/nspawn tools
Description-md5: 06057fffc2ba14e4be80360a092a18b4
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the case, thank you for this. :)

Comment: I replaced focal with focal-updates on `etc/apt/sources.list` and it works like a charm.

Comment: @AdamKrawczyk Theres a great related Q&A regarding the different sources [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279002/what-is-the-difference-between-suite-and-suite-security-repositories-in-apt)